# .htaccess rewrite everything to index.php or static files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htacces is setted to handle all request to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Is working right but now I found myself in a situation that I need make the files from img folder accessible from url, follow my folder structure and the new line on .htaccess:

Folder Structure

```
.htaccess // File
index.php // Folder
webroot // Folder
  img // Folder inside webroot
```

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^webroot/.+\.(jpg|gif|png|ico)$ - [L] // New line

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

htaccess says if I get `http://example.com/webroot/img/something.jpg` goes to, if not handle anything else to index.php.

How can I access my statics files without call webroot on url?
like this `http://example.com/img/something.jpg` with my current folder structure??

Comment: Your new line doesn't rewrite anything. But instead of mapping/redirecting the wrong img/ paths, just use `<base href=>` like everyone else.

Comment: Why not just move your files to `/img` instead of rewriting from `webroot/img` if you don't want webroot in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you want to remove `webroot` from url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /webroot/img/$1 [L]
```